# Hold printing jobs on Windows Server until a user confirms the job

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, printing

When sharing a printer using Windows 7 or Windows Server (2008+), is there any way to hold the print job until a user walks up to the print server and confirms their print job in the queue?

If there is nothing like this built into the Windows printer sharing or Windows print server, are there any free, open source, or low-cost solutions that can be integrated into an existing Windows printing environment?

CUPS solutions will not work in our as our printers do not officially support PCL printing from Linux (Gutenprint will not work for our needs).

*UPDATE* I may have found a working solution for making CUPS printing work in Windows. If I can get this to work I will post my full solution here.

Comment: You'd really want to do this at the printer level and not involve the print server ...many new copiers support printing to a "document box".

Comment: Not sure. Seen the difference at my customer. I dump a job at a print server, then walk over to ANY printer, put my ID card on the scanner and select the jobs to print. VERY convenient.

Comment: Part of the problem is that our printers don't support this, we'd have to replace them in order to get features like this.

We get something like this when we configure our users to use "Secure Printing", which requires them to enter a PIN at the printer before their job prints, but if we forced users to have to remember a PIN every time they print we'd get a lot of complaints or requests due to forgetting their PIN.

The way I'm looking at it, if they select their job from a list in Windows, it's familiar enough that we wouldn't have backlash from the users about tightening printing security.